# Trouble binding ViewModel to View, as part of a ListViewItem DataTemplate with ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reactive, reactiveui

I'm having some issues trying to display a view in a ListViewItem Data template in reactive. I have a ListView in, for example ReceiptView.xaml whose source is bound like such

```
this.WhenActivated(d =>
  {
     this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Items, view => 
                    view.ReceiptListView.ItemsSource).DisposeWith(d);
  });

where in ReceiptViewModel - Items is an IObservableCollection<ItemsViewModel>
```

The ItemTemplate for the ListView is as such

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ItemViewModel}">
       <DockPanel
              Width="{Binding Path=ViewportWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}}"
              Margin="0,5"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Background="Transparent">
              <views:ItemView />
         </DockPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
```

It is here where I'm unsure whether to use this mechanism for displaying the view or the ViewModelViewHost ViewModel="{Binding ItemViewModel}"..

My ItemView.xaml.cs is as such

```
public partial class ItemView : ReactiveUserControl<ItemViewModel>, ISupportsActivation
{
    public ItemView()
    {
        Activator = new ViewModelActivator();

        InitializeComponent();

        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Name, v => v._Name.Text).DisposeWith(d);
        });
  }
}
```

Currently with the usage above, it never goes into the WhenActivated function, if I remove the ISupportsActivation functionality, it just crashes out with the message ViewModel is null. I was wondering what the correct way is to get something like this working?

I have tried using ViewModelViewHost and setting the ViewModel property inside the DataTemplate instead of above but it doesn't even reach the ItemView.xaml.cs backing code. The dependencies are setup initially  like:

```
dependencyResolver.Register(() => new ItemView(), typeof(IViewFor<ItemViewModel>));
```

Comment: You aren't setting any view model inside your datatemplate dockpanel. You can use ViewModelViewHost https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-location/#viewmodelviewhost if you want automatic view resolution. If you decide to use this or not you'll need to use a xaml binding is this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Glen, I did use the ViewModelViewHost ViewModel={Binding ItemViewModel} in its place but it never resolves the view. The view, I believe is setup correctly in my App.cs with: Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new ItemView(), typeof(IViewFor<ItemViewModel>));

Answer (score 1):

The solution, in respect of actually getting it to work, was a matter of binding issue. I needed to use

```
<ViewModelViewHost ViewModel="{Binding .}" />
```

within the `DataTemplate`.